# What's the general disjunction rule for n events?

Tags: probability

The general disjunction rule for events $A_1$ and $A_2$ is $$P(A_1 \vee A_2) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) - P(A_1 \wedge A_2).$$
What about when there are $n$ events? What is $P(\bigvee_i^n A_i)$ where $A_i$ is the $i$th event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general formula is
$$ P(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \sum_{i \in C_{k,n}} P(A_{i_1}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_k}) $$
where $C_{k,n}$ is the set of all ordered $k$-uples $i_1 < \cdots < i_k$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

You can prove it by induction, it’s not conceptually difficult but painful enough to write.

Answer (score -1):

Using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)
$$
(\neg A) \vee (\neg B) \Leftrightarrow \neg (A \wedge B) 
$$
$$
A \vee B\Leftrightarrow \neg ((\neg A) \wedge (\neg B)) 
$$

$$
P(\bigvee_i^n A_i) = 1 - P(\bigwedge_i^n (\neg A_i))
$$